# Access query to count instances with a different start and end value

Tags: sql, ms-access-2016, subquery

I'm having difficulty creating a query in Access and am not sure it is even possible.  The client has revised the requirements from their original request.  I need a count of columns A and B.  The table will be in date and then time order (see below).

Each time a block of time starts with a zero and ends with a 105, the count (for column A) increases by 1.  If 100 appears in column B; within that block, then the count (for column B) increases by 1.  There could be several code 105 in column 5 before the next block starts.

For the sample below, the Col A count = 2 and the Column B count = 1

Start: 1:06:12 AM
End:   2:28:12 AM
Contains 100 (column b) in the block of times

Start: 2:28:20 AM
End:   5:12:04 AM
Does not contain 100 (column b) in the block of times

```
|   Date    |   Time     |  A  |  B  |
| 1/20/2021 | 1:06:12 AM |  0  | 100 |
| 1/20/2021 | 1:06:16 AM |  0  | 100 |
| 1/20/2021 | 1:06:20 AM |  0  | 100 |
| 1/20/2021 | 2:28:12 AM | 105 | 100 |
| 1/20/2021 | 2:28:16 AM | 105 | 100 |
| 1/20/2021 | 2:28:20 AM |  0  | 10  |
| 1/20/2021 | 3:50:08 AM |  0  | 10  |
| 1/20/2021 | 3:50:12 AM |  0  | 10  |
| 1/20/2021 | 3:50:16 AM |  0  | 10  |
| 1/20/2021 | 5:12:04 AM | 105 | 10  |
| 1/20/2021 | 5:12:08 AM | 105 | 10  |
| 1/20/2021 | 5:12:12 AM | 105 | 10  |
```

I know I could do this in Excel without any issues but the client is looking for a query to do the same thing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Very unusual problem.  You can assign the "block" to A by counting the number of 105s that appear on or after each row.  The groups have a constant value.  Then -- if I understand correctly -- filter to the `0` rows and aggregate.

This is trickier than it needs to be in MS Access which does not support `count(distinct)` or window functions.  But I think this does what you want:

```
select count(*) as num_a, sum(has_b) as num_bs
from (select grp, max(iif(b = 100, 1, 0)) as has_b
      from (select t.*,
                   (select count(*)
                    from t as t2
                    where t2.datetime >= t.datetime and
                          t2.a = 105
                   ) as grp
            from t
           ) as t
      where t.a = 0
      group by grp
     ) as t;
```

Comment: @gordonlinoff.............Thanks...........I appreciate your help.  I'm stopping for tonight but will test this tomorrow and let you know how it goes.  Thanks again for all of your advice....

Comment: @gordonlLinoff............I replaced the table names and column names in the sample with the actual values.  See below:

select count(*) as num_a, sum(has_b) as num_bs
from (select Date, max(iif(F702Load = 100, 1, 0)) as has_b 
          from (select A_F702.*, 
                       (select count(*) 
                        from A_F702 as t2 
                        where t2.Time >= t.Time and t2.F702Push = 105 
                      ) as grp 
                  from A_F702
                 ) as t 
          where t.F702Push = 0 
          group by Date
        ) as t;

Comment: When I run this, I'm getting a pop up for a parameter value (t.Time).  I'm not sure where I messed up.  Can you help.

The table I'm running this against has multiple dates and the results I'm looking for should be something like this for each date

Date1      Count of F702Push      Count of F702Load

Comment: @Shaves . . . This part looks wrong:  `from A_F702 ) as t `.  I think `from A_F702  as t) as t `.

Comment: @gordonlinoff........Thanks.........I'll give that a try

Comment: @gordonlinoff...........That helped.  But, I'm not getting the results I expect.  There are over 40K records for 1/20/21 and 1/21/21.  I am expecting to see 1/20/21 F702Push (col A) = 17 and F702Load (column B) = 2 AND 1/21/20 F702Push (col A) = 17 and F702Load (column B) = 0

I tried adding "Date" to the first SELECT statement but I'm getting an error message that says "Your query does not include the specified expression 'Date' as part of an aggregate function.  Thanks again for all of your help.